# How to implement usermode timer in C?

Tags: c++, c, timer

How we can implement our own timer function in Windows without using Library functions? Should we deal with assembly language instructions?

Comment: Without using a single Library function? Or not using specific functions? I do not see how you can get system time without a lib call.

Comment: I need to know how a simple time can be implemented. Of course it's possible to rely on platform APIs. Without using that how it's possible to implement that?

Comment: In windows SetTimer should be enough. If you can't rely on platform APIs then can reprogram the clock chip on you own (i8042).

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the precision and resolution you require.

Assuming you need more than second precision, it's popular to wrap/use the `RDTSC` instruction. But you can also just use the Win32 API, the `QueryPerformanceCounter()` is widely used for this.

Answer (score 0):

Many APIs like Intel's Threading Building Blocks (http://threadingbuildingblocks.org), OpenMP (http://openmp.org), SDL (http://libsdl.org) or SFML (http://sfml-dev.org), and I think also OpenGL (http://opengl.org) implement a timer or a wrapper around a timer.

Saying "without using Library functions" is a bit vague: Which library do you mean specifically? In the end, you have to use some library function, or inline assembly, because C++ doesn't have timing functionality in the core language. And without any timer processor or some other timing hardware in whichever form (*), there is no way to tell the time, not vaguely, not exactly.

(*) That includes internet time providers.

Answer (score 0):

get the atomclock time from an internet time service.

else you will always deal with some sort of library-functions with which you can talk to the BIOS, which is the part that makes the tick-tock from the Quartz visible to the OS.